# A problem I didn't know since high school algebra

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine all positive integers which can be written as a sum of two squares of integers.

This is a problem I saw when I was in high school...

1. sum of two squares of integers can be (4k, 4k+1, 4k+2, but no 4k+3?)

Comment: A partial solution to your first question is the collection of *squares* which can be written as a sum of two squares of integers. These are the Pythagorean triples, and can be generated by the formula $k^2 (m^2+n^2)^2$ for positive integers $k,m,n$.

Comment: They are numbers in which the prime factors of the form $4k+3$ appear to even powers. Begin reading from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares). To pass from the solution for primes to all the numbers use [Brahmagupta's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_identity).

Comment: As for your high school problem, notice that $(4k)^2=16k^2=4n$, $(4k+1)^2=16k^2+8k+1=4n+1$,$(4k+2)^2=16k^2+16k+4=4n$,$(4k+3)^2=16k^2+24k+9=4n+1$. (The values of $n$ are different.) So a square is never of the form $4k+3$. So a square can only have remainder either $0$ or $1$ when divided by $4$. When you add the squares, the remainders add, so the remainders can only be $0$,$1$, or $2$.

Comment: Concisely, consider $x$ and $y$ as two arbitrary integers. We can have $x,y\equiv \{0,1,2,3\}\pmod{4}\implies x^2,y^2\equiv \{0,1\}\pmod{4}\implies x^2+y^2\equiv \{0,1,2\}\pmod{4}$

Comment: A big thanks to @Nathanson common. One more question, how to check the integer of the form 4n, and 4n+2 can be written as $a^{2}+b^{2}$ ?

Comment: @user131605 Not all integers of that form are sums of two squares. For example, $6=2\cdot3=4\cdot1+2$ is not the sum of two squares. In the characterization above we must look at the factorization. In the case of $6$, it is divisible by the prime $3=4\cdot0+3$, which appears to the power of $1$. Since this power is not even then $6$ is not the sum of two squares. If we had considered $18=2\cdot3^2$ then it would be the sum of two squares: $18=3^2+3^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square of an even number is a multiple of $4$ (i.e. $4k^2)$, and that of an odd number is a multiple of $4$ plus $1$ (i.e. $4(k^2+k)+1$). So the sum of two squares is a multiple of $4$, plus $0$, $1$ or $2$.

Anyway, not all numbers for the form $4k$, $4k+1$ or $4k+2$ are sums of two squares (take $12$, $21$ and $6$), so this does not really answer the question.

A better criterion was given by Euler: an integer is the sum of two squares ($0$ allowed) iff its prime factors of the form $(4k+3)$ have an even multiplicity.

$$\begin{align}
2&= 2\  \\
3&= \color{red}{ 3\  } \\
4&= 2^{2}\  \\
5&= 5\  \\
6&= 2\  \cdot \color{red}{ 3\  } \\
7&= \color{red}{ 7\  } \\
8&= 2^{3}\  \\
9&= \color{green}{ 3^{2}\  } \\
10&= 2\  \cdot 5\  \\
11&= \color{red}{ 11\  } \\
12&= 2^{2}\  \cdot \color{red}{ 3\  } \\
13&= 13\  \\
14&= 2\  \cdot \color{red}{ 7\  } \\
15&= \color{red}{ 3\  } \cdot 5\  \\
16&= 2^{4}\  \\
17&= 17\  \\
18&= 2\  \cdot \color{green}{ 3^{2}\  } \\
19&= \color{red}{ 19\  } \\
20&= 2^{2}\  \cdot 5\  \\
21&= \color{red}{ 3\  } \cdot \color{red}{ 7\  } \\
22&= 2\  \cdot \color{red}{ 11\  } \\
23&= \color{red}{ 23\  } \\
24&= 2^{3}\  \cdot \color{red}{ 3\  } \\
25&= 5^{2}\  \\
26&= 2\  \cdot 13\  \\
27&= \color{red}{ 3^{3}\  } \\
28&= 2^{2}\  \cdot \color{red}{ 7\  } \\
29&= 29\  \\
30&= 2\  \cdot \color{red}{ 3\  } \cdot 5\  \\
31&= \color{red}{ 31\  } \\
32&= 2^{5}\  \\
33&= \color{red}{ 3\  } \cdot \color{red}{ 11\  } \\
34&= 2\  \cdot 17\  \\
35&= 5\  \cdot \color{red}{ 7\  } \\
36&= 2^{2}\  \cdot \color{green}{ 3^{2}\  } \\
37&= 37\  \\
38&= 2\  \cdot \color{red}{ 19\  } \\
39&= \color{red}{ 3\  } \cdot 13\  \\
40&= 2^{3}\  \cdot 5\  \\
41&= 41\  \\
42&= 2\  \cdot \color{red}{ 3\  } \cdot \color{red}{ 7\  } \\
43&= \color{red}{ 43\  } \\
44&= 2^{2}\  \cdot \color{red}{ 11\  } \\
45&= \color{green}{ 3^{2}\  } \cdot 5\  \\
46&= 2\  \cdot \color{red}{ 23\  } \\
47&= \color{red}{ 47\  } \\
48&= 2^{4}\  \cdot \color{red}{ 3\  } \\
49&= \color{green}{ 7^{2}\  } \\
50&= 2\  \cdot 5^{2}\  \\
51&= \color{red}{ 3\  } \cdot 17\  \\
52&= 2^{2}\  \cdot 13\  \\
53&= 53\  \\
54&= 2\  \cdot \color{red}{ 3^{3}\  } \\
55&= 5\  \cdot \color{red}{ 11\  } \\
56&= 2^{3}\  \cdot \color{red}{ 7\  } \\
57&= \color{red}{ 3\  } \cdot \color{red}{ 19\  } \\
58&= 2\  \cdot 29\  \\
59&= \color{red}{ 59\  } \\
60&= 2^{2}\  \cdot \color{red}{ 3\  } \cdot 5\  \\
61&= 61\  \\
62&= 2\  \cdot \color{red}{ 31\  } \\
63&= \color{green}{ 3^{2}\  } \cdot \color{red}{ 7\  } \\
64&= 2^{6}\  \\
65&= 5\  \cdot 13\  \\
66&= 2\  \cdot \color{red}{ 3\  } \cdot \color{red}{ 11\  } \\
67&= \color{red}{ 67\  } \\
68&= 2^{2}\  \cdot 17\  \\
69&= \color{red}{ 3\  } \cdot \color{red}{ 23\  } \\
70&= 2\  \cdot 5\  \cdot \color{red}{ 7\  } \\
71&= \color{red}{ 71\  } \\
72&= 2^{3}\  \cdot \color{green}{ 3^{2}\  } \\
73&= 73\  \\
74&= 2\  \cdot 37\  \\
75&= \color{red}{ 3\  } \cdot 5^{2}\  \\
76&= 2^{2}\  \cdot \color{red}{ 19\  } \\
77&= \color{red}{ 7\  } \cdot \color{red}{ 11\  } \\
78&= 2\  \cdot \color{red}{ 3\  } \cdot 13\  \\
79&= \color{red}{ 79\  } \\
80&= 2^{4}\  \cdot 5\  \\
81&= \color{green}{ 3^{4}\  } \\
82&= 2\  \cdot 41\  \\
83&= \color{red}{ 83\  } \\
84&= 2^{2}\  \cdot \color{red}{ 3\  } \cdot \color{red}{ 7\  } \\
85&= 5\  \cdot 17\  \\
86&= 2\  \cdot \color{red}{ 43\  } \\
87&= \color{red}{ 3\  } \cdot 29\  \\
88&= 2^{3}\  \cdot \color{red}{ 11\  } \\
89&= 89\  \\
90&= 2\  \cdot \color{green}{ 3^{2}\  } \cdot 5\  \\
91&= \color{red}{ 7\  } \cdot 13\  \\
92&= 2^{2}\  \cdot \color{red}{ 23\  } \\
93&= \color{red}{ 3\  } \cdot \color{red}{ 31\  } \\
94&= 2\  \cdot \color{red}{ 47\  } \\
95&= 5\  \cdot \color{red}{ 19\  } \\
96&= 2^{5}\  \cdot \color{red}{ 3\  } \\
97&= 97\  \\
98&= 2\  \cdot \color{green}{ 7^{2}\  } \\
99&= \color{green}{ 3^{2}\  } \cdot \color{red}{ 11\  } \\
100&= 2^{2}\  \cdot 5^{2}\  \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: May I ask, where does "A better criterion was given by Euler: an integer is the sum of two squares (0 allowed) iff its prime factors of the form (4k+3) have an even multiplicity." from?
And how to proof this criterion?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html

Answer (score 2):

Every integer $n$ can be expressed as $n=4k+r$ for $r=0,1,2,3$. $r$ is called the remainder after division by 4. Now $n^2 = (4k+r)^2 = 4^2k^2 + 8kr + r^2$.

If $r = 0$ then $r^2=0$. So $n^2=4k'$ for some $k'$.

If $r=1$ then $r^2=1$. So $n^2=4k'+1$ for some $k'$.

If $r=2$ then $r^2=4$. So $n^2=4k'$ for some $k'$.

If $r=3$ then $r^2 = 9 = 2\cdot 4 + 1$. So $n^2 = 4k'+1$ for some $k'$.

Thus the square of every integer can be expressed as $n^2 = 4k + r$ where $r=0$ or $r=1$.

Thus the sum of two squares can have the following remainders after division by 4:

$$1+1=2$$
$$1+0=1$$
$$0+0=0$$

Note that we cannot have a remainder of 3, since this has exhausted all the possibilities.

---

A neat thing that you can show with a bit of imaginary numbers is that the product of two numbers that are a sum of squares is again a sum of squares.

$$(n^2+m^2)(a^2+b^2)$$ $$= (n+im)(n-im)(a+ib)(a-ib)$$ $$= (an-bm+i(nb+ma))(an-bm-i(nb+ma))$$
$$=(an-bm)^2+(nb+ma)^2$$

Thus if we take $10=3^2+1$ and $8=2^2+2^2$ we can write $80$ as the sum of two squares:

$$80 = (6-2)^2+(6+2)^2 = 4^2 + 8^2.$$

Comment: So, if I want to find out all positive integers can be written as $a^{2}+b^{2}$. First, they must be of the form $4n, 4n+1, 4n+2$. Second, say 1,2,4,5,8,9,10 are the positive integers satisfies $a^{2}+b^{2}$, then, how do I know if there is a large prime of the form 4n+1, which may be written as $a^{2}+b^{2}$?

Comment: Okay, I find the answer through @Nathanson common. One more question, how to check the integer of the form 4n, and 4n+2 can be written as $a^{2}+b^{2}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

For $a,b$ in $a^2+b^2$, consider three cases:

1) Both $a,b$ are even. Then $a^2+b^2=4k^2+4k'^2$ which is of the form $4k$.

2) Both $a,b$ are odd. Then $a^2+b^2=8k+1+8k'+1=4(2k+2k')+2$ which is of the form $4k+2$.

3) $a,b$ have the deifferent parity. WLOG suppose that a is odd and b is even. Then $a^2+b^2=8k+1+4k'=4(2k+k')+1$ which is of the form $4k+1$